# IdentationError: Unexpected indent following Django Tutorial

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm following the tutorial on django on the following link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/

Specifically the part where its adding the **str** methods on both classes, but I'm getting the indent error!

I used python before and after looking for a while I still can't see my error!

See the image with the hidden characters of my code, what is it!? It's been driving me crazy:

[image: Error on django]

See the error when trying to run the python shell:

[image: Error on shell]

So what could it be? I am legit running out of ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: @Dan-Dev As soon as I saw your message looked up my picture and yes... the lines from the model (the  first ones) are god damnit spaces... Thank you very much, how can I mark your comment as the one that solved my question?

Comment: @Dan-Dev can you potst it as an answer so I can mark it as you answered it correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

> Indentation is rejected as inconsistent if a source file mixes tabs and spaces in a way that makes the meaning dependent on the worth of a tab in spaces; a TabError is raised in that case.

if you are consistent in your use of tabs and spaces this problem will go away.